# Can I request reviews of my unittests and where should that go?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In the near future, I'm probably gonna make a sizable post requesting the review of a Python project of mine.

While its development hasn't been exactly test-*driven*, I am crafting the unit tests alongside the real code and making sure stuff works together.

Is it reasonable to request a review of the unit tests too, and if so, should the test module go in the same post as the originally mentioned review, or in a separate one? The project and its testing module have separate github repos that I'll include in both posts, so that reviewers have access to the tools I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of questions about [unit-testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing).  Just include the tests to be reviewed as part of the question.

The size of the question is a concern only if it exceeds 64 kB.